# Printing integers tiled horizontally - Python3

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I'm trying to obtain the following: i want to print a range of integers, but if the integer contains more than 10 digits, the '1' in '10' needs to be printed on top.

e.g.:

> 6 - > 123456
>
> 13 - >...................1111
>
> ..........1234567890123

Remark, that if it contains less then 10 digits, there's no 'upper line' printed. And the '.' should be replaced just by spaces, but the editor won't let me do that

I've tried the following:

```
line10 = ''
line1 = ''

if length > 10:
    for i in range(length):
        if (i + 1) // 10 == 0:
            line10 += ' '
        else:
            line10 += str((i + 1) // 10)


for i in range(length):
    line1 += str((i + 1) % 10)

if length > 10:
    print(line10)
print(line1)
```

And: this works, but how can you make it work for let's say 100 or 1000, without having to copy the lines of code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant solution to your problem, but I believe this does what you require:

```
def number_printer(n):

    lines = [[] for m in range(len(str(n)))]

    for i in range(1, n+1):
        diff = len(str(n))-len(str(i))

        if diff > 0:
            for z in range(diff):
                lines[z].append(" ")
            for x, y in enumerate(str(i)):
                lines[x+diff].append(y)
        else:
            for x, y in enumerate(str(i)):
                lines[x].append(y)

    for line in lines:
        print "".join(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    number_printer(132)
```

Essentially, it is checking the length of each number it counts through against the lenght of the number you wish to print (in this example 132). Wherever it finds a difference (where diff > 0), it appends the appropriate number of blank spaces so all the numbers align (e.g. for the number 12 it would append 1 blank space, as the difference in length between 12 and 132 is 1).

Hopefully this is what you were after!